# Angular Directive using '=' scope & controllerAs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a Directive to decode and encode some information. Basically I am storing 5 binary pieces of information in a database using an Int (giving each bit a value of 16, 8, 4, 2, 1).

I need to ways of editing the data: as an Int, and as bits. But I have lots of problems connecting them up, and these are (deliberately) compounded by using controllerAs notation.

1) When I change the Int nothing changes in the bits. This is because the link function only seems to load once - how can I have a change in a model update information in a Directive?

```
<input ng-model="c.int" type="text" />
<testdir score="c.int"></testdir>
```

My Directive includes:

```
scope: {
  score: '='
},
controller: function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.recChange = function() {
    // convert bits to score
  }
},
controllerAs: 'd',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  // convert score to bits
```

and a link function that converts score into `scope.recommendations`, which is an array 5 bits.

2) When I change the bits (and have controllers using $scope) then the Int does change. But I cannot find a way to use controllerAs - the link function uses `scope` whereas my controller needs a `d.` prefix.

```
template: "<label ng-repeat='(key, recommendation) in recommendations' class='checkbox-inline'>

// template: "<label ng-repeat='(key, recommendation) in d.recommendations' class='checkbox-inline'> \
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pO0izlIPYfbgCQYMhjLm?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `scope.score` instead of using the attribute value of the score since you're using the two-way data binding notation `=` in your scope declaration for score. Additionally, when changes for a certain exists, then simply place watcher for that value and apply your changes therein.

**UPDATE**: Simply add your directive's name in the `require` key value of your directive definition, and you should be able to access your controller in your link function as the fourth argument.

**[FORKED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/54NslbP4WwtAcQh3PDFF?p=preview)**

```
.directive('testdir', function() {
  var recommendationCategories = ['16RotM', '8Top5', '4Price', '2Cuisine', '1Area'];

  return {

    require: 'testdir',

    scope: {
      score: '='
    },

    controller: function () {
       // .....
    },

    controllerAs: 'd',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      console.log(ctrl);

      scope.$watch('score', function() {
        scope.recommendations = {};
        var score = parseInt(scope.score);
        // decode recommendations
        // convert to binary string
        var bitVal = score.toString(2);
        //pre-pad with "0"
        var e = recommendationCategories.length - bitVal.length;
        bitVal = "0".repeat(e) + bitVal;

        recommendationCategories.forEach(function (cat, idx) {
          scope.recommendations[cat] = {checked: (bitVal[idx]=="1") ? true : false};
        });

        // add a field for closed too
        scope.recommendations.closed = {checked : (score < 0)};
      });
    },
    template: "<label ng-repeat='(key, recommendation) in recommendations' class='checkbox-inline'> \
                <input type='checkbox' ng-model='recommendation.checked' ng-change='d.recChange()'/>{{key}} \
      -        </label>"
    // template: "<label ng-repeat='(key, recommendation) in d.recommendations' class='checkbox-inline'> \
  }

});
```

Comment: Great - that solves part 1, but leaves part 2 of the question

Comment: It's actually in the **[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-)** documentation

Comment: Sorry, but am still struggling to get encoded value, `vm.score`,  back out of the directive and into the parent http://plnkr.co/edit/PEWAzuPGJJleQqKW21Ds?p=preview

Comment: ... unless I use a `$scope`, which I'm trying to deprecate

Answer (score 1):

After your "controllerAs" value you need to add **bindToController:true**